# Close iBeacons monitoring on background and with app closed

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

Im building a simple ios app with IBeacon, Im using startMonitoringForRegion for detect beacons. Thats AppDelegte.m code:

```
    NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"0040C159-12F6-4FC3-9189-87C069FFE5CF"];
    NSString *regionIdentifier = @"iBeacons region 1";
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID: beaconUUID identifier: regionIdentifier ];
    self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
```

Then on didDetermineState callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

    if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {
        //Start Ranging
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
        NSLog(@"didDetermineState -->enter region");
    }
    else{
        //Stop Ranging
        [manager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
        NSLog(@"didDetermineState -->exit region");
    }

}
```

This is working fine on foreground, background or with the app closed when the iBeacons are far each other. But i detect some problems when the iBeacons are close each other.

After performing several tests I have concluded that RangingBeaconsInRegion doesn't working on background or with app closed, only monitoring works.

The app will be launched into the background for about 5 seconds when you enter or exit the region of a beacon, and it will get a callback to the didDetermineState: forRegion: method. You can here do ranging in the background for this five second period, after which iOS will suspend your app again.

This is perfect when iBeacons are far from each other. The problem comes when iBeacons are too close and the callback didDetermineState: not called for the exit of the iBeacon region before you enter the next iBeacon region.

Is there any way to force the region exit manually? Or some other way to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, How to check that beacon detection is working fine when application is closed. I am not able to test it. Thank you.

Comment: You can try sending local notifiactions, or creating records in your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a real problem.  When beacons have overlapping transmissions and your regions encompass all them them, you won't get entry/exit events as one disappears and the other appears.

There are a number of ways to address this problem, but none of them are a perfect solution.  You can:

- Extend ranging for up to 3 minutes in the background.
- Construct your beacon identifiers and regions so you get exit/entry events as much as possible.

You can read a more detailed discussion the first technique here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try your solution. The demo on the blog is all I need? I do not have much practice with backgroundtasks. Anyway, it would be a crazy idea stop and start ranging every time that a iBeacon is detected?

Comment: I implemented your first solution using the blog detailed information and it works as expected. Thank you!! regards!